# Magento 1.9 Order not able to cancel payment done by PayPal?

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal-express, voiding

After **void** the order from PayPal, the order not able to cancel in magento backend the error like  **PayPal gateway has rejected request. Authorization is voided (#10600: Authorization voided).**
How can i cancel the order?

Comment: Have you checked log file ?

Comment: It shows : Authorization voided

Comment: what is error code get in log

Comment: error code ; 10600

Comment: is the transaction type void?

Comment: @Nickool I did manually void the order from PayPal, in magento back-end i can't able to cancel the order.

Comment: @Nickool Is any changes i need to do further?

Answer (score 0):

If a buyer using PayPal contacts you to cancel an order, or you wish to cancel an order, you can void the authorization. Voiding the authorization will free up any funds reserved for the transaction in PayPal.

Note: Once voided, the transaction buttons disappear from the PayPal Transaction Control panel. You will no longer be able to capture, refund, or reauthorize an order once the authorization has been voided. If you inadvertently void an authorization, you will need to contact the buyer to replace the order, or arrange an alternate payment method. If you already captured funds, you will have to perform a refund.

To void an authorization:

From the Store Manager, click the Orders link.
View the order for which you wish to void an authorization.
(The individual order review page will display a PayPal Transaction Control panel for orders where PayPal was the payment method).
enter image description here

3. Click the Void Transaction button.
   The transaction will be processed and the status displayed for you on a confirmation screen. If successful, the transaction will be marked "OK", and after clicking OK to return to the Order Review page, you will see "Voided" in the Payment section of the page.

Link: https://www.questarter.com/q/paypal-gateway-has-rejected-request-authorization-is-voided-10600-authorization-voided-10_29800.html